# save facebook comment to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I save a comment made with facebook comments to a mysql database? I want to be able to search through the comments on another page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean where you comment on, for example, your wall, the comment to get to your mysql database?

if so, you need to study Facebook API (Graph API)

Comment: Sorry I should have explained better. I put facebook comments on a page on my site, I want to search through those comments on my site. I have looked into the facebook API and can display the graph of comments on a page on my website, but have not found how to use/access data in the graph.

Comment: so, for what i understand you have a facebook.com/pageid page, and all comments for that facebook page can be searched from your www.yoursite.com, is that right?  If is so, i don't really know how to do it, but a start its to retrive all comments from your fb page to a database using Graph API, and to do this first you have to create an FB App ...

Comment: Sorry let me explain better. I have a page on a server I own that has a facebook comments iframe. I already made a facebook app. I can display the graph data for the comments on screen, but I don't know how to save them or store them into a variable or something more useful then just displaying text on screen.

Comment: cant you get graph data into an array and then back into a database?? i dont see the issue ...

Comment: I don't know how to do that...  -____-

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

// displays some comments for a certain url
$url = 'http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/';

// fql multiquery to fetch all the data we need to display in one go
$queries = array('q1' => 'select post_fbid, fromid, object_id, text, time from comment where object_id in (select comments_fbid from link_stat where url ="'.$url.'")',
                 'q2' => 'select post_fbid, fromid, object_id, text, time from comment where object_id in (select post_fbid from #q1)',
                 'q3' => 'select name, id, url, pic_square from profile where id in (select fromid from #q1) or id in (select fromid from #q2)',
                 );

// note format json-strings is necessary because 32-bit php sucks at decoding 64-bit ints :(
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?format=json-strings&method=fql.multiquery&queries='.urlencode(json_encode($queries))));

$comments = $result[0]->fql_result_set;
$replies = $result[1]->fql_result_set;
$profiles = $result[2]->fql_result_set;
$profiles_by_id = array();
foreach ($profiles as $profile) {
  $profiles_by_id[$profile->id] = $profile;
}
$replies_by_target = array();
foreach ($replies as $reply) {
  $replies_by_target[$reply->object_id][] = $reply;
}

/**
 * print a comment and author, given a comment passed in an an array of all profiles.
 * @param object $comment as returned by q1 or q2 of the above fql queries
 * @param array $profiles_by_id, a list of profiles returned by q3, keyed by profile id
 * @returns string markup
 */
function pr_comment($comment, $profiles_by_id) {
  $profile = $profiles_by_id[$comment->fromid];
  $author_markup = '';
  if ($profile) {
    $author_markup =
      '<span class="profile">'.
        '<img src="'.$profile->pic_square.'" align=left />'.
        '<a href="'.$profile->url.'" target="_blank">'.$profile->name.'</a>'.
      '</span>';
  }

  return
    $author_markup.
    ' ('.date('r', $comment->time).')'.
    ': '.
    htmlspecialchars($comment->text);
}

print '<html><body>';

// print each comment
foreach ($comments as $comment) {
  print
    '<div style="overflow:hidden; margin: 5px;">'.
      pr_comment($comment, $profiles_by_id).
    '</div>';
  // print each reply
  if (!empty($replies_by_target[$comment->post_fbid])) {
    foreach ($replies_by_target[$comment->post_fbid] as $reply) {
      print
        '<div style="overflow:hidden; margin: 5px 5px 5px 50px">'.
          pr_comment($reply, $profiles_by_id).
        '</div>';
    }
  }
}


?>
```

Comment: this fetches fb data ... from here you can improove

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it.

The first way is to get all comments in one go. You have to do it periodically to get new comments, and avoid duplicating the old ones in your database.

This can be achieved by accessing the Graph API with the url of your page:

> https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://example.com/your_page

This returns comments in JSON which you have to parse. If there are too many, there will be an 'paging' hash telling you the address of the next page.

---

The second way is to track new comment and saves them immediately. This avoids the refetched duplicate problem. This will require the use of [Javascript and Facebook js events](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/).

```js
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response) {
  var commentQuery = FB.Data.query('SELECT fromid, text FROM comment WHERE post_fbid=\'' + response.commentID + '\' AND object_id IN (SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url=\'' + response.href + '\')');
  FB.Data.waitOn([commentQuery], function () {
    text = commentQuery.value[0].text;
    // Use your preferred way to inform the server to save comment
    $.post( 'http://example.com/comment', text )
  });
});
```

The example below fetches the comment at client side. But you can also do it at server-side.

Of course you'll need to include Facebook's Javascript library, and implement the posting action (http://example.com/comment) on your server.

Answer (score 0):

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create',
function(response) {
onCommentCreate(response.commentID,response.href); //Handle URL on function to store on database

alert(response.href); //it gives you url
}
);

function onCommentCreate(commentID,href) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'handlecomment.php',
        data: {commentid:commentID,href:href},
        success: function(result)
        {
        alert(result);
        }
    });
}

//hadlecomment.php 


<?php 
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
  $commentid=$_POST['commentid'];
  $url=$_POST['href'];
  $pid=substr($url,strpos($url, 'comments')+8);

 // Remember to copy files from the SDK's src/ directory to a
  // directory in your application on the server, such as php-sdk/
  require_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');

  $config = array(
    'appId' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);
  $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
 $accesstoken=$facebook->getAccessToken();

 if($user_id) {

  // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
  // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
  try {
        $facebook->setAccessToken($accesstoken);
        $fql = 'SELECT text from comment where id = ' . $commentid;
        $ret_obj = $facebook->api(array(
                                   'method' => 'fql.query',
                                   'query' => $fql,));
$comment= $ret_obj[0]['text'] ;
     $insert_comment="insert into comments(pid,comment) values($pid,$comment)";
mysql_query($insert_comment);


  } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
    // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
    // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
    // just ask the user to login again here.
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
    echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
    error_log($e->getType());
    error_log($e->getMessage());
  }   
} else {

  // No user, so print a link for the user to login
  $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
  echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

}
  ?>

?>


//YOu need to set data-href of comment should be look like this...
//i am using more comments on my website so i looped through to add comment 


while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($query)))
{
  $pic_id=$result['pic_id']; // i have saved unique pic id in my database for all images so  i am    

//retrieving that here

<div class="fb-comments" style=' position:relative;left:55px;top:10px;'  data-href="<?php echo 'http://www.lpuphotography.edulogics.in/votography.php/comments' . $pic_id; ?>" data-width="470" data-num-posts="2"></div>

}

//if you are using single comment

<div class="fb-comments" style=' position:relative;left:55px;top:10px;'  data-href="<?php echo 'http://www.lpuphotography.edulogics.in/votography.php/comments101'  ?>" data-width="470" data-num-posts="2"></div>

//101 is comment id , u can set what ever you want
```

Comment: Please add some explanation as well, it makes a better answer.